# Does Eclipse IDE complain duplicate entries for handlers in plugin.xml?

Tags: eclipse

I mistakenly have duplicate entries in my plugin.xml. But the eclipse IDE didn't complain. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Semantics for extension points vary. Eclipse only performs basic data type validation on the extension data at design time. The extension point handlers typically perform further validation at runtime, but the depth of that validation varies from one extension point to another. Problems detected at runtime will be reported in the error log.